# Is the following integral of a pdf an identity, i.e. always true?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, density-function, integral

I am reading a paper and the author starts a proof with this

$$
p(\hat{R}|R) = \int p(\hat{R},\theta|R)d\theta
$$
p is the density function.

Is this something that is always true? Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Overly short version: It's essentially the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), stated for conditional probabilities as described there.

Comment: Ah, that help. The next line in the proof is $ = \int p(\hat{R}|\theta,R)p(\theta|R)d\theta $ which seems line a more direct restatement of the stuff on your Wikipedia page. It's not clear to me why this follows from the first line, or why the author didn't just start with the second line.

Comment: Your difficulty is with $P(A,B|C)=P(A|B,C).P(B|C)$?

Comment: It was but now that you wrote it out, I see that it is the same operation as $P(A,B)=P(A|B).P(B)$, correct?

Comment: In effect, yes; you can establish a conditional version of that fairly easily. (Though I'm kind of surprised you're dealing with integrals like those without already having been shown it.)